# Using onclick with selection to load textarea content from mysql db in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

[The content shows but the selection option remains the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqlNc.png)I'm considerably new to code igniter and I've been trying to set up a selection form so that when an option has been selected, the content would be loaded from the db (mysql). I've got most of it down already but the only problem is with the select section. The content shows when an option is selected but the selection area doesn't reflect the option shown. It shows the default. Here's the view:

```
    <form accept-charset='utf-8' action="<?php echo base_url() ?>note/def_messages" method='GET'>
                        <label for='msg_types'>Select one the default message types:</label>
                        <select id='msg_types' name='msg_types' onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                <option selected id="Templates" >Please select message type ...</option>
                                <option value = "Qbalance">Quarterly Balances</option><br>
                                <option value = "Felicitations">Felicitations</option><br>
                                <option value = "Birthday">Birthday</option><br>
                                <option value = "Contributions">Contributions</option><br>
                                <option value = "News">News</option>
                            </select><br><br>

                            <div class="alert alert-success">
<textarea id="messages" rows = "7" cols = "120" style="text-align:'left'" placeholder = "Blah Blah Blah ..."><?php if (isset($result)){foreach($result as $row){echo  trim(stripslashes(htmlentities($row['message'])));}
                                    }else{
                                       echo "Nothing has been selected";
                                    }
                                ?></textarea><br><br>
                                <button type="submit" class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send</button>
                        </form>
```

Here's the Controller part:

```
function def_messages(){
    $data = Array();
    $types=$this->input->get('msg_types');

    //echo $types;

    $data['result'] = $this->db->query("SELECT message FROM messages WHERE msg_name = '$types'")->result_array();   
    $data['msg_type'] = $types;

    $this->load->view('notifications', $data);  
}




     public function index($page='notifications'){ 
        if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/'.$page.'.php')){
            show_404();
        }else{
            $this->load->view($page);
        }
     }
```

Comment: `var_dump($data['result']);` in `def_messages` function and check it's content.may be it's empty

Comment: @FastSnail array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["message"]=> string(67) "We wish you the best celebrations as you celebrate this special day" } } ... I know whats wrong. Just don't know why.

Comment: that seems to be ok.i tested your code and woking fine.do you see any errors?

Comment: Test on separate area. I test on your def_message function and change the query into this `$data['result'] = array(
      array('message'=>'We wish you the best celebrations as you celebrate this special day'),
      array('message'=>'We wish you a merry chrismas and a happy new year')
     );` and it works fine. and in `echo trim(stripslashes(htmlentities($row['message'])))` you might want to add `."\n";` at the back of that line.. yes, your code works fine..

Comment: I just edited the question and added an image link. It shows the issue i'm having.

Comment: Do you want the msg_types select droplist to be 'birthday'? You're not doing anything to set it.

Comment: @ourmandave How do i set it?